# pythonanywhere: Something went wrong :-(

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere, django-settings

When I'm uploading my DRF app to pythonanywhere, the server shows the following log error: `2022-07-15 01:06:14,933: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Rest_API_Framework.settings'`.

However, I don't understand why, since if we look at `/var/www/art1x_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py` folder, everything looks fine to me:

```
import os
import sys

path = 'home/art1x/Rest_API_Framework'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Rest_API_Framework.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

In addition, the settings.py folder in my django app:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Rest_API_Framework.settings')
```

Please point out any mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you don't forget the correct path syntax.

In my case, I forgot to put '/' in front of my path.

Change `'home/art1x/Rest_API_Framework'` to `'/home/art1x/Rest_API_Framework'`